# What to use when index value of array isn't unique?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got a question.
Today I started making an accordion menu (for FAQ's).
I am trying to make it so only one item is open at the time.
It kinda works, I am using the index value to have one open at the time.
But when you take a look at my array you can see that there are for example 5 index[0]'s because I sorted the question in category's.
I know that I can manually add Id's to my questions but I am curious if there is another way then manually adding Id numbers.

Btw, I am using Vue.js (Nuxt.js). Couldn't find an answer on my question.

Snippet down below (not a working example but  just to show you the code).

Thank you in advance.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: null,
      questionRows: {
        questionRow1: {
          category1: {
            title: 'Over het systeem',
            questions: {
              question1: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 1',
              },
              question2: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 2',
              },
              question3: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 3',
              },
              question4: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 4',
              },
            },
          },
          category2: {
            title: 'Ander onderwerp',
            questions: {
              question1: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 5',
              },
              question2: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 6',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        questionRow2: {
          category1: {
            title: 'Over Notafy',
            questions: {
              question1: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.',
              },
              question2: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 7',
              },
            },
          },
          category2: {
            title: 'Campagnes',
            questions: {
              question1: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 8',
              },
              question2: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 9',
              },
              question3: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 10',
              },
              question4: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 11',
              },
            },
          },
          category3: {
            title: 'Overig',
            questions: {
              question1: {
                question: 'Wat is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?',
                answer: 'Dit is antwoord 12',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItem(index) {
      if (this.isActive === index) {
        this.isActive = null;
        return;
      }
      this.isActive = index;
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<div v-for="category in questionRows.questionRow1" :key="category.id">
          <div class="flex items-center mb-3">
            <h3 class="text-blue text-lg font-bold">{{ category.title }}</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <div v-for="(question, index) in category.questions" :key="question.id">
              <div :class="{ 'active-class' : isActive === index}" class="justify-between w-full min-h-min  bg-white rounded-2xl select-none">
                <div class="cursor-pointer" @click="toggleItem(index)">
                  <div :class="{'pb-5' : isActive !== index}" class="flex justify-between items-center text-button pt-6 pl-10 pr-7">
                    <h3 class="font-bold">{{ question.question }}</h3>
                    <font-awesome-icon v-if="isActive === index" :icon="['fas', 'sort-up']"/>
                    <font-awesome-icon v-else :icon="['fas', 'sort-down']"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p v-if="isActive === index" class="mt-3 text-sm text-blue pl-10 pr-7 pb-5">
                  {{ question.answer }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div v-for="category in questionRows.questionRow2" :key="category.id">
          <div class="flex items-center mb-3">
            <h3 class="text-blue text-lg font-bold">{{ category.title }}</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <div v-for="(question, index) in category.questions" :key="question.id">
              <div :class="{ 'active-class' : isActive === index}" class="justify-between w-full min-h-min  bg-white rounded-2xl select-none">
                <div class="cursor-pointer" @click="toggleItem(index)">
                  <div :class="{'pb-5' : isActive !== index}" class="flex justify-between items-center text-button pt-6 pl-10 pr-7">
                    <h3 class="font-bold">{{ question.question }}</h3>
                    <font-awesome-icon v-if="isActive === index" :icon="['fas', 'sort-up']"/>
                    <font-awesome-icon v-else :icon="['fas', 'sort-down']"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p v-if="isActive === index" class="mt-3 text-sm text-blue pl-10 pr-7 pb-5">
                  {{ question.answer }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The index value of an array is always unique.

Comment: @SteveTomlin if you have multiple for loops in your template and all of the key bindings are to the index values, then you will have multiple `key=0`, `key=1` and so on...

Comment: In your code there is `:key="category.id"` and `:key="question.id"` but I don't any question id nor category id in your `questionRows` object

Comment: @CedricCholley you're right but I added that to remove errors. Doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a concatenation of the question index and the category index. This way the newly created index would always be unique.

In your example I've added `categoryIndex`, renamed `index` to `questionIndex` and elsewhere replaces `index` by `` `${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}` ``

```html
<div v-for="(category, categoryIndex) in questionRows.questionRow2" :key="category.id">
  <div class="flex items-center mb-3">
    <h3 class="text-blue text-lg font-bold">{{ category.title }}</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-col gap-3">
    <div v-for="(question, questionIndex) in category.questions" :key="question.id">
      <div :class="{ 'active-class' : isActive === `${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}`}" class="justify-between w-full min-h-min  bg-white rounded-2xl select-none">
        <div class="cursor-pointer" @click="toggleItem(`${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}`)">
          <div :class="{'pb-5' : isActive !== `${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}`}" class="flex justify-between items-center text-button pt-6 pl-10 pr-7">
            <h3 class="font-bold">{{ question.question }}</h3>
            <font-awesome-icon v-if="isActive === `${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}`" :icon="['fas', 'sort-up']" />
            <font-awesome-icon v-else :icon="['fas', 'sort-down']" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p v-if="isActive === `${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}`" class="mt-3 text-sm text-blue pl-10 pr-7 pb-5">
          {{ question.answer }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very well explained. I only have one more problem, I also have a ```questionRow1``` so when I add the same things on that HTML it for example opens the first one in ```questionRow1``` AND in ```questionRow2```... I'll edit my question to show you ```questionRow1``` aswell. Sorry that I didn't add that in directly. Do you have any solutions for that? :)

Comment: Oh, I already solved it by just adding a custom word behind it. For questionRow1 I change it to: ```${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}-questionRow1``` and for questionRow2 
```${categoryIndex}-${questionIndex}-questionRow2```..   Thank you so much for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

generally when for whatever reason I can't use in object id's for the `key` I use this technique to make them unique:

suppose I have two arrays one for questions and one for question items then I might do something like this:

```
<question v-for="(question, i) in questions" :key="`question-${i}`"></question>
```

then for the question items I can have:

```
<question-item v-for="(questionItem, i) in questionItems" :key="question-item-${i}"></question-item>
```

this will generate keys like `question-0` and `question-item-0` which makes them unique

Comment: Thanks for your answer, checked and this answer worked aswell. I just personally prefer Cedric's answer :). Although its quite the same..

Comment: that is a good answer, and I think works best when you have nested for loops in the template, when you have multiple for loops in different places of the template you can't concatenate indexes and you can append a name to them to avoid `duplicate key` error